# How to test a repository and return list in Mockito

Tags: junit

I want to test my method getAllUsers that return a list of undefined datatypes, however, my code never compiles and I do not know what I am doing wrong.

This is my test method.

```
@Query(value = "SELECT b.* "
        + "FROM Benutzer b "
        + "ORDER BY b.name", nativeQuery = true)
List<?> getAllUsers();

@Test
public void testGetAllUsers() {
    UserManagementService localMockRepository = Mockito.mock(UserManagementService.class);
    Mockito.when(localMockRepository.getAllUsers()).thenReturn(List<?> someList);
}
```

I expect a list with all users in it.

Comment: what is error you are getting. What is someList?

Comment: Apparently, you've completely missed the point of Mockito. If it compiled, your code wouldn't test your code at all. It would test Mockito. A mock is a fake object that basically replaces the code of your real object by code that does nothing. If you want to test a repository, you must **not** mock the repository.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I am testing Mockito. I will change that immediately.